# Error when attempting to run new blank hybrid app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I currently get the following error when attempting to run a hybrid app using the new cordova ctp for Visual Studio 2013.

```
Error   11  The command
""C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli"
prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir .
--projectName "BlankCordovaApp2"" exited with code 1.   C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets 115 5   BlankCordovaApp2
```

Do I need to install something else?

Comment: I just tried the same with a TypeScript based hybrid app and the same error occurs.  It won't even work for windows platform if I change it in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain cases, VS does not immediately detect the Android path after installation. Rebooting your machine is the only option for now.

Answer (score 0):

for me I just deleted the `bld` folder and everything has become right